# NDFrame.convert_dtypes() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype_backend'

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I'm trying to visualise spatial data using `Lonboard` Python lib dedicated for BIG DATA, here is the error I find while writing these lines:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from lonboard import PathLayer, Map

# Create MultiPathLayer
layer = PathLayer.from_geopandas(gdf_lines, width_min_pixels=0.8)

# Create Map object
map_ = Map(layers=[layer])

# Display the map
map_
```

Here is the error in the picture : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ulx0o.png)

I already tried to upgrade pandas version, but the problem persists.